# erasing textfield after submit content

Tags: javascript, html

I want to erase content of textfield after adding option into select list, here is the html code example:

```
<select size="15" style="width:230px" style="text-align:right" id="theaterSelectControl">
                            <option>111</option>
                            <option>222</option>
                            <option>333</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>
                        </p>
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" name="theater_name" value="" id="theater_name" style="width:225px">
                        </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <input type="button" onclick="createOption()" value="add">      <!-- add to list button -->
                </td>
</tr>
```

here is js code:

```
function createOption()
{
    var theaterSelectControl = document.getElementById('theaterSelectControl'); 
    var currentText = document.getElementById('theater_name').value;
    var objOption = document.createElement("option");
    objOption.text = currentText ;
    objOption.value = currentText ;
    theaterSelectControl.options.add(objOption); 
    document.getElementById('add_option').onclick = createOption;   
        resetField();
} 
function resetField() 
{
    document.getElementById('theater_name').value = "";
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: what currently happens with that code?

Comment: document.getElementById('add_option') Where is that element?

Comment: nothing - it adds the new option but not clear the field.

Comment: The script seems to be OK. Do you have a `<form>` surrounding the controls? If you do, probably it's being submitted before you can see the effect of `createOption()`.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem - fixed... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your event listener is inside the function it calls, it's causing problems.

```
document.getElementById('add_option').onclick = createOption;
```

Put it outside `createOption();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm so out of practice with regular JS that I can only produce a jQuery example for you. Hope it helps!

**LIVE Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jp27y/

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    createOption();
});

function createOption(){
    $('#theaterSelectControl').append($("<option></option>").text($('#theater_name').val()));     
    $('#theater_name').val("");
}
```